# Kafka topic not created automatically on remote kafka after spring boot start(and create on local kafka server)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

1) I start kafka on my machine

2) I start my spring boot server with config:

```
@Bean
public NewTopic MyTopic() {
    return new NewTopic("my-topic", 5, (short) 1);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> greetingProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> unpMessageKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(greetingProducerFactory());
}
```

result - server is start successfully and create `my-topic` in kafka.

But if I try do it with remote kafka on remote server - topic not create.

and in log spring write:

```
12:35:09.880 [                  main] [INFO ]    o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: [] AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
```

If I add this bean to config:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "remote_host:9092");
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

topic create succesfully.

1) Why it happens?

2) Do I have to create  `KafkaAdmin` ? why for the local Kafka is not required?

**EDDIT**

My current config:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: remote:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value("${response.topics.topicName}")
    private String topicName;

    @Bean
    public NewTopic responseTopic() {
        return new NewTopic(topicName, 5, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

After start I see:

```
bootstrap.servers = [remote:9092]
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
```

...

But topic not create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KafkaAdmin is the kafka spring object that looks for NewTopic objects in your spring context and creates them. If you do not have a KafkaAdmin no creation will take place. You can explicitly create KafkaAdmin (as you show in your code snippet) or indirectly order its creation via the spring kafka configuration properties.

KafkaAdmin is a nice to have it is not related to production or consumption to/ from topics for your application code.

**EDIT**

You must have something wrong; I just tested it...

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: remote:9092
```

and

```
2019-03-21 09:18:18.354  INFO 58301 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    
        : AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [remote:9092]
    ...
```

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically configure a `KafkaAdmin` for you, but it uses the application.yml (or application.properties). See [Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Scroll down to `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=`. That's why it works with `localhost` (it's the default). You also don't need a `ProducerFactory` or template; boot will create them for you from properties.

Comment: I eddit question. I add more details

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot will automatically configure a `KafkaAdmin` for you, but it uses the application.yml (or application.properties). See [Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Scroll down to `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=`. That's why it works with `localhost` (it's the default).

You also don't need a `ProducerFactory` or template; boot will create them for you from properties.

Comment: I expected this. but it does not work. I have this yaml config: `spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: remote_host:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` and when I start aplication topic not create

Comment: And if I do not need create `ProducerFactory` how can I autowire `kafkaTemplate`? I create another question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280173/the-correct-way-for-creation-of-kafkatemplate-in-spring-boot

Comment: You must have something wrong; see the edit to my answer; works fine for me.