# The correct way for creation of KafkaTemplate in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I try configure **apache kafka** in **spring boot**  application. I read this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-kafka)  and follow the steps:

1) I add this lines to `aplication.yaml`:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka_host:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

2) I create new Topic:

```
    @Bean
    public NewTopic responseTopic() {
        return new NewTopic("new-topic", 5, (short) 1);
    }
```

And now I want use `KafkaTemplate`:

```
private final KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate;

public KafkaEventBus(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}
```

But Intellij IDE highlights:

[image]

To fix this I need create bean:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> myMessageKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(greetingProducerFactory());
}
```

And pass to constructor propirties `greetingProducerFactory()`:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> greetingProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka_hist4:9092");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

But then what's the point of setting in **application.yam**l if I need create ProducerFactory manual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can safely ignore IDEA's warning; I have no problems wiring in Boot's template with different generic types...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55280173Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55280173Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so55280173", "foo");
            if (foo.template == template) {
                System.out.println("they are the same");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so55280173", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    Foo(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

}
```

and

```
they are the same
```

Comment: I get error: `Failed to construct kafka producer` when try send message

Comment: That has nothing to with wiring; I suggest you ask a new question with more information, stack trace etc.

Comment: I confused the serializer and deserializer classes for the key so there was an error `Failed to construct kafka producer`. Now It work, but IDEA still show warning(Because of this, I did not understand much and thought that it was necessary to create manually)

Comment: Sounds like IDEA is more strict than spring :(

Answer (score 5):

By default `KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>` is created by Spring Boot in [`KafkaAutoConfiguration` class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/36c1c051b8106371d37f8a747cea0e369a8e5c84/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.java#L71). Since Spring considers generic type information during dependency injection the default bean can't be autowired into `KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]>`.

Comment: I try inject differents: `KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>`, just `KafkaTemplate` - in all cases highlights

Comment: `KafkaTemplate` is a raw type, this will have side effects in your class. Better to use `KafkaTemplate<?, ?>` or `KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>`.

Comment: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>' type found.`

Comment: Did you remove your own `myMessageKafkaTemplate` bean?

Comment: I believe you can ignore IDEA's warning - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue initially, but when I executed it gave no errors and worked fine.

Ignore **Intellij IDEA's warning**, it may be a IDEA's bug figuring out autowired components.